# Rails How to give options in date time select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to implement a datetime_select option for a form. I was using a simple date selector like below before hand but the requirements have changed.

```
<%= f.datetime_select :ends_at, :start_year => Date.current.year %>
```

What I want to implement instead is to give users only three options as: "One hour", "Two hours", "Three hours" for selection. The corresponding values for the chosen option sent as POST through the form would be calculated from the time the submit button is pressed.

How can I give these options for the users for a datetime data type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using

```
<%= f.select :ends_at, options_for_select(ApplicationHelper::TIMER.map { |obj| [obj['time'], obj['val']] })%>
```

in the form itself.

Where Timer is defined as:

```
module ApplicationHelper
    TIMENOW = DateTime.now
    TIMER = [{"time"=>"Half Hour", "val"=> TIMENOW + 0.5.hour},{"time"=>"One Hour", "val"=> TIMENOW + 1.hour}, {"time"=>"One Day", "val"=> TIMENOW + 24.hour}, {"time"=>"Three Days", "val"=> TIMENOW + 3.day}, {"time"=>"Seven Days", "val"=> TIMENOW + 7.day}]
end
```

in the ApplicationHelper

Answer (score 1):

Okay you can do something like that:

In your **Model** define:

```
TIMER = [{"time"=>"One Hour", "val"=>"1"}, {"time"=>"Two Hours", "val"=>"2"}, {"time"=>"Three Hours", "val"=>"3"}]
```

In your **form** use a different select field:

```
<%= f.select :time_to_end, options_for_select(Model::TIMER.map { |obj| [obj['time'], obj['val']] }) %>
```

Then in the model allow `time_to_end` parameter as a `attr_accesible`.

```
attr_accessible :time_to_end
```

Also, add a before save callback to change the `ends_at` field:

```
before_save :update_ends_at_field

private
def update_ends_at_field
   self.ends_at = Time.now + time_to_end.to_i.hours 
end
```

I didn't tested the code above. Hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I ended up defining TIMER = [{"time"=>"Half Hour", "val"=> DateTime.now + 0.5.hour},{"time"=>"One Hour", "val"=> DateTime.now + 1.hour}, {"time"=>"One Day", "val"=> DateTime.now + 24.hour}, {"time"=>"Three Days", "val"=> DateTime.now + 3.day}, {"time"=>"Seven Days", "val"=> DateTime.now + 7.day}] in Applicationhelper and calling it in the form <strong>Ends After: </strong><%= f.select :ends_at, options_for_select(ApplicationHelper::TIMER.map { |obj| [obj['time'], obj['val']] })%>

Comment: Oh, great. Then you can close the question by accepting an answer.